# Don't understand cause of exception

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('elasticbeanstalk')
code_pipeline = boto3.client('codepipeline')

def put_job_success(job, message):
    print "Putting job success"
    print (message)
    code_pipeline.put_job_success_result(jobId=job)

def put_job_failure(job, message):
    print('Putting job failure')
    print(message)
    code_pipeline.put_job_failure_result(jobId=job, failureDetails={'message': message, 'type': 'JobFailed'})

def get_user_params(job_data):
    user_parameters = job_data['actionConfiguration']['configuration']['UserParameters']
    decoded_parameters = json.loads(user_parameters)
    print user_parameters

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        # Extract the Job ID
        job_id = event['CodePipeline.job']['id']

        # Extract the Job Data
        job_data = event['CodePipeline.job']['data']

        # Extract the params
        params = get_user_params(job_data)

        # Get the list of artifacts passed to the function
        artifacts = job_data['inputArtifacts']

        put_job_success(job_id, 'successfuly done')

    except Exception as e:

        # If any other exceptions which we didn't expect are raised
        # then fail the job and log the exception message.
        print('Function failed due to exception.')
        print(e)
        put_job_failure(job_id, 'Function exception: ' + str(e))

    print('Function complete.')
    return "Complete."
```

Getting Error:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 48, in lambda_handler
    put_job_failure(job_id, 'Function exception: ' + str(e))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'job_id' referenced before assignment
```

Please help!

Comment: All you have to do is read the error message. `local variable 'job_id' referenced before assignment` means that you are trying to use `job_id` before it was initialized. When you are catching an exception, the variable in `try` block is not initialized yet. You can add `job_id = None` or some other default value before `try` block to assure it will be assigned before referencing to it.

Comment: Before the `UnboundLocalError` is raised, `print(e)` should be outputting the `KeyError` that I presume caused control to switch to the `except` block before `job_id` was given a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing in your `try` block is guaranteed to run once you hit the `except` block. This includes the `job_id` assignment. If you want to get rid of the error, you can try:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):  
    job_id = None
    try:  
        # Extract the Job ID  
        job_id = event['CodePipeline.job']['id']  

        # Extract the Job Data    
        job_data = event['CodePipeline.job']['data']   

        # Extract the params  
        params = get_user_params(job_data)  

        # Get the list of artifacts passed to the function  
        artifacts = job_data['inputArtifacts']  

        put_job_success(job_id, 'successfuly done')  

    except Exception as e:  

        # If any other exceptions which we didn't expect are raised  
        # then fail the job and log the exception message.  
        print('Function failed due to exception.')   
        print(e)  
        put_job_failure(job_id, 'Function exception: ' + str(e))
```